# Bash - Misuse of quotes I believe - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: bash, curl, cookies

To tell you the truth, im baffled - i thought id understood the basics of bash by now but that isnt the case.

**PROBLEM**: I want the use the curl wrapper as shown below to make a POST request to an api, *but* when I use the wrapper, nothing happens

*The wrapper works fine in other instances (ie. ${_CURL} -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} ${URL})*

**IDEA1**: so i thought it might have to do with the quotation around the json object, which i had problems with in the past so i ended up inserting "'${JSON}'", which didnt work

**IDEA2**: in the curl wrapper, I placed all arguments ("-b ${COOKIES} $@") into quotes but nothing

curl wrapper

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# sets headers to use cookies
# ${Cookies} is set and translates to an absolute path of ./cookie-file.txt

if [ -f "${COOKIES}" ]; then
  curl -b "${COOKIES}" $@
else
  curl $@
fi
```

Json Object for i think its of importance

```sh
JSON=$( jq -n -r \
           --arg login $LOGIN \
           --arg pass ${PASS_INPUTS[@]} \
           '{username: $login, password: $pass}')
```

the file id use it in

```sh
#JSON is located right above the following line
#_CURL being the path to the wrapper i exported 
# Does not even send a request to the URL at $V2/auth/login
  RESPONSE=$($_CURL -s \
       --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
       --request POST \
       --data "$JSON" \
       $ARGS \
       "${V2}/auth/login")
   echo $RESPONSE

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This is what i had previously but Id rather not
# works just fine
[ ! -f "cookie-file.txt" ] && ARGS="-c cookie-file.txt" || ARGS="-b cookie-file.txt"
  
  RESPONSE=$(curl -s \
       --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
       --request POST \
       --data "$JSON" \
       $ARGS \
       "${V2}/auth/login")
   echo $RESPONSE
```

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) automatically detects [this](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2068) and other common problems

Comment: heard of that before, but here we are - not brightest under the lowlife @thatotherguy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is around $@, try :

```
#!/bin/bash
# sets headers to use cookies
# ${Cookies} is set and translates to an absolute path of ./cookie-file.txt

if [ -f "${COOKIES}" ]; then
  curl -b "${COOKIES}" "$@"
else
  curl "$@"
fi
```

Without double quotes, arguments with spaces are not handled properly.

Comment: THX MAN

 *good gahd in heaven, bless this man for his unorthodox knowledge of bash* @Philippe

Comment: glad i pointed that out in the title, misuse of quotes or the absence of them...